# Proxy issue with Vagrant laravel homestead

Tags: windows, laravel, vagrant

I am trying to use Laravel homestead on a windows PC with Vagrant behind a proxy. I am using 'vagrant-proxyconf' and have updated my vagrantfile with the proxy details

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-proxyconf")
    config.proxy.http = "http://$my_account:$my_password@yproxyserver.com.au:8080"
    config.proxy.https = "http://$my_account:$my_password@myproxyserver.com.au:8080"
    config.proxy.no_proxy = "localhost,127.0.0.1"
  end
end
```

However, whenever I try to 'vagrant up'I get the error:

> The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded:
>   failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy

I have also tried making the proxy https, with no improvement.

```
config.proxy.https = "https://$my_account:$my_password@myproxyserver.com.au:8080"
        config.proxy.no_proxy = "localhost,127.0.0.1"
```

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

Are there things I can try to narrow down where the issue is? e.g. is it possible to test connection to proxy, test proxy user authentication... using the Vagrantfile

FYI: I am using GIT Bash command-line on windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Could you solve it? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Setting this variables via the Windows GUI made it possible for me to connect through our proxy (Right click on Computer > Properties > Advanced System Configuration > Advanced options tab > Environment Variables).

```
http_proxy=http://proxy:1234

https_proxy=http://proxy:1234
```

I spent the whole day on this. It didn't work for me setting it through CMD with the set command, through Git Bash with export nor writing it in the Vagrantfile.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I encountered this 2 days ago still.

Setting proxy didn't work for me because there is nothing in homestead that sets the proxy before the composer self-update command is run. So it always fails just after:

```
homestead: Running: script: Update Composer
```

So I had to go into scripts/homestead.rb and remove

```
composer self-update --no-progress
```

From the file in the "Updating composer" section (look for where it echos this out)

Everything worked fine for me then. Just use vagrant-proxyconf in the Vagrantfile as normal to get proxy settings into the VM and then do a composer self-update after everything is setup if you want/need.

Hope that helps someone out. I lost 2 days wondering what was going wrong with proxyconf when it was nothing to do with that